# 180 shift PWM signals

Tags: arduino, power-electronics, pwm

I am a student of electrical and computer engineering and am currently working on a project that involves the study of a multiphase buck converter or synchronous buck converter. I need to shift these two PWM signals 180º but I'm not understanding why it doesn't work, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I'm using Arduino UNO.

That's the code that I´m using:

```
const int pwmPin1 = 9;  // Pin for PWM output 1
const int pwmPin2 = 10; // Pin for PWM output 2

void setup() {
  // Set the PWM pins as outputs
  pinMode(pwmPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pwmPin2, OUTPUT);

  // Configure Timer/Counter 1 for PWM generation on pin 9
  TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1) | _BV(WGM11);  // Set OC1A and OC1B on Compare Match, Fast PWM mode
  TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13) | _BV(CS10);                  // Fast PWM mode, no prescaler
  ICR1 = 399;                                      // Set the top value (399 for approximately 20,000 Hz at 16 MHz clock speed)

  // Configure Timer/Counter 2 for PWM generation on pin 10
  TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM20);  // Set OC2A and OC2B on Compare Match, Phase Correct PWM mode
  TCCR2B = _BV(CS20);                              // No prescaler (full clock speed)
  OCR2A = 99;                                      // Set the top value (99 for approximately 20,000 Hz at 16 MHz clock speed)
}

void loop() {
  // Generate 50% duty cycle PWM signals with 180-degree phase shift
  OCR1A = 199;  // Set the compare value for PWM output 1 (199 for 50% duty cycle)
  OCR1B = 199;  // Set the compare value for PWM output 2 (199 for 50% duty cycle)

  OCR2A = 49;   // Set the compare value for PWM output 2 (49 for 50% duty cycle, 180-degree phase shift)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a 180 degree phase shift (a time delay) or do you really want to logically invert the signals?

Answer (score 3):

### For Inverting of PWM Signal

This is not what your question asks for, but it seems from your comments, this is what you want.

Inverting the PWM output is simple. You need only change the code in your question from:

```
TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1) | _BV(WGM11);  // Set OC1A and OC1B on Compare Match, Fast PWM mode
```

To:

```
TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1) | _BV(COM1B0) | _BV(WGM11);  // Set OC1A and OC1B on Compare Match, Fast PWM mode. OC1B output is inverted.
```

This will result in the OC1A (digital pin 9) and OC1B (digital pin 10) being the same PWM signal, but inverted.

```
                 ___          ___
Pin 9:  ________|   |________|   |__
        ________     ________     __
Pin 10:         |___|        |___|
```

You don't need the second timer (Timer 2) code for this. In fact that code is controlling digital pin 11 which you don't appear to be using. That output will be of a different frequency and phase compared to the two Timer 1 outputs as explained in more detail in the remainder of this answer.

If you truly just want an inverted signal, you need read no further.

---

### For 180 Degree Phase Shift

Your question asks how to produce two PWM signals with a 180 degree phase shift. The signals would resemble:

```
           ___           ___
Pin 9:  __|   |_________|   |_________
                  ___           ___
Pin 10: _________|   |_________|   |__
```

As far as I can tell, there isn't anything in your code which specifically phase shifts either PWM signal by 180 degrees.

The first problem is that you have timer 1 running in fast PWM mode, and timer 2 separately running in phase-correct PWM mode. These two modes do different things - one creates a one-sided waveform, the other creates a central waveform:

```
       Full Speed                       Phase Correct
   : tOn :    tOff   :            : tOff/2 : tOn : tOff/2 :
   :_____:           :___         :        :_____:        :
___|     |___________|            :________|  ^  |________:
   ^                                          ^
 phi=0                                      phi=0

duty = tOn / (tOn + tOff)
```

Changing the duty cycle of a timer running phase correct PWM and second running full speed PWM will change the relative phase between the timers.

The second issue is that timers 1 and 2 are not strictly synchronous to each other. You cannot start the two times simultaneously, which means that you cannot guarantee precise phase of the two timers. Furthermore they use potentially different clock sources if you enable prescalars.

Thirdly, timer 1 has a period of `400` clock cycles, whilst timer 2 has a period of `100 x 2` clock cycles, so the latter is running at twice the frequency. This will give different PWM frequencies!

---

So, how can we do this?

Both outputs on the same timer have the same phase, this cannot be changed because the phase is set based on the TCNT value being either 0 (fast PWM) or TOP/2 (phase correct PWM). So we have to use two timers, as you've summised.

In order to generate two PWM signals of exactly correct relative phase shift, we need both timers to be in the same mode (see above how the different modes have different "0" points), and we also need to be able to stop, update, and start both counters at exactly the same time. This is the tricky part, but it is possible.

The ATMega328 has three timers, 0, 1, and 2. Timers 0 and 1 use the same prescalar clock source, which means they are synchronous to each other. Timer 2 uses its own prescalar clock source, so we can't guarantee synchronisation. So let's instead use 0 and 1.

Timer 0 is an 8-bit timer, and you want to control the frequency, so we can either use it in mode `111` (fast PWM with OCR0A as the top), or `101` (phase correct PWM with OCR0A as the top). Because we are using OCRA as the top value, that means OC0A cannot be used for PWM output. That leaves us with OC0B, or digital pin **5** in arduino speak.

To be synchronous, we want both timers to be in the same mode, with the same period. This means we should operate timer 1 in either mode `1110`/`1111` (fast PWM with ICR1/OCR1A as top). or `1010`/`1011` (phase correct PWM with ICR1/OCR1A as top). You can use ICR1 or OCR1A as the top value - using ICR1 means you can use OC1A as a PWM output if you desire, digital pin 9.

The clock rate for the Arduino is 16MHz. You want a 20kHz PWM frequency. This means we need a period of 800 clock cycles (fast PWM) or 400 cycles (phase-correct PWM). This is however too large for the 8-bit timer 0. So we use a prescalar.

The lowest suitable prescalar is /8. This means the timer would run at 2MHz, giving a period of either 100 cycles (fast PWM) or 50 cycles (phase-correct PWM). The latter is really too small to get a decent accuracy on the duty cycle, so let's use fast PWM mode.

```
// Timer 0 setup
TCCR0A = _BV(COM0B1) | _BV(WGM01) | _BV(WGM00); //Pin 5, Fast PWM with OCR0A as Top
TCCR0B = _BV(WGM02) | _BV(CS01); //Prescalar of /8
OCR0A = 100 - 1; //Period of 100 cycles @ 2MHz = 20kHz
// Timer 1 setup
TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(WGM11); //Pin 9, Fast PWM with ICR1 as Top
TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13) | _BV(WGM12) | _BV(CS11); //Prescalar of /8
ICR1 = 100 - 1; //Period of 100 cycles @ 2MHz = 20kHz
```

So the question now is how do we ensure phase between the two timers. Well, if both timers are synchronous and in the same mode, then the phase is controlled by the TCNT value. In fast PWM mode, the rising edge occurs at TCNT = 0, so if we set `TCNT0 = 0`, and `TCNT1 = 50`, then the second timer will be half of our 100 clock cycle period out of phase - or 180 degree phase shift.

But now we still have the same problem as before. How can we ensure that the `TCNT` values are shifted exactly if we can only write to one register at a time?

This is where the cool feature of using the timers with the same prescalar clock source comes in to play. Enter the `GTCCR` register. If we set the `TSM` bit in `GTCCR`, the prescalar clock source stops running. This halts the clock to both timers simultaneously! If we clear the bit, we start the clock simultaneously too.

The `GTCCR` register also has a flag to reset the prescalar divider for both timers too, ensuring that both clocks are at exactly the same phase too.

```
// Stop and resynchronise the clock to both timers
GTCCR = _BV(TSM) | _BV(PSRSYNC);
// Update the timer values
TCNT0 = 0;  // Phase of 0 degrees
TCNT1 = 50; // Phase of 50/100 * 360 = 180 degrees
// Set the duty cycle. With period of 100 cycles, OCR value = duty cycle in %
OCR0B = 20; // Any value 0-99.
OCR1A = 20; // Set both to the same value.
// Start the clock synchronously to both timers
GTCCR = 0;
```

So now we can stop both timers simultaneously, ensure the `TCNT` values are updated to the correct phase shift, set bot to the same PWM duty cycle, and then set both timers going simultaneously and synchronously.

---

In Arduino world, timer 0 is used for functions such as millis() and delay(). Using timer 0 for PWM will break these functions.

If you wish to use millis() too, then you can either modify the core libraries to use Timer 2 for the delay functions instead, or accept that a delay of 1000 milliseconds will actully be only about 50 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but with the changes that you suggested, the second signal disapeared and the duty cycle is no longer 50%. I replaced my code with yours but it didn't work.

Comment: @JoséAlves The code generates PWM outputs on digital pin 5 and pin 9, so you'll need to change those too. The duty cycle is configurable, set OCR0B/OCR1A to 50 to get 50% duty cycle.

Comment: @JoséAlves That being said, it appears from your comments on the other answer you are looking to invert the signal, not phase shift it. This can be accomplished much more simply. You only need Timer 1. Adding ` | _BV(COM1B0)` to the `TCCR1A = ...` line in your original code will result in the signal on pin 10 being inverted. You don't need any of the timer 2 code.

Answer (score 0):

**Inverting ≠ 180° phase shift.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIMjbq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a squarewave it can look like the phase has been shifted but it hasn't. For a PWM signal it will not look like a 180° phase-shift.

I don't see where you are modifying the PWM value. Can you clarify in your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I think the inversion is what i need. Can you tell me what I need to do to invert the second PWM signal? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: A simple inverter gate would do.

Comment: @Uwe: An inverter gate introduces a small delay, which if the signals are being used to control an H-bridge, might cause shoot-through (catastrophically high current that will quickly destroy the circuit).  To protect against shoot-through, it's common to have dead time.  You may have used the phrases "make-before-break" and "break-before-make".

Comment: @BenVoigt The PWM frequency is 20 kHz only, an inverter delay of about 10 ns is very close to zero. The H bridge would need much more delay between break and make to be protected  against shoot-through. 10 ns would not hurt.